# N1QL query does not use the expected index

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to create a couchbase N1QL query that will use a specific index.
This is my index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_progressTest ON testbucket(payload.type, payload.display, payload.status, meta(testbucket).id) where payload.type = "Test" AND payload.display = true AND payload.status != "IN_PROGRESS" using GSI;
```

And this is my query (I use explain to see which index it will use):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT meta(jmbucket).id FROM testbucket WHERE payload.type = "Test" AND payload.display = true AND payload.status != "IN_PROGRESS";
```

But it seems that the query will not use my index.
If I remove the last part of the "WHERE" clause from both the index and query, then everything works fine.

What should I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: forgot to mention I am using couchbase 4.1.1

Comment: Remove the meta().id from your index definition. It is already part of the index. So by adding it explicitly, you are just storing it twice and wasting space.

Comment: @Kirk I will give it a try, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Couchbase 4.5.

If you want to use 4.1, remove this from your index:

```
AND payload.status != "IN_PROGRESS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Couchbase is Case Sensitive. Make sure that the columns specified in your Create Index script matches the case of the elements in the document. I found this out the hard way. #lessonlearned